# Bash: How do I check (and return) the results of a command filtered by file content

Tags: bash

I executed a command on Linux to list all the files & subfiles (with specific format) in a folder.

This command is:

```
ls -R | grep -e "\.txt$" -e "\.py$"
```

In an other hand, I have some filenames stored in a file .txt (line by line).

I want to show the result of my previous command, but I want to filter the result using the file called `filters.txt`.

- If the result is in the file, I keep it
- Else, I do not keep it.

How can I do it, in bash, in only one line?

I suppose this is something like:

```
ls -R | grep -e "\.txt$" -e "\.py$" | grep filters.txt
```

An example of the files:

```
# filters.txt

README.txt
__init__.py
```

##### EDIT 1

I am trying to a file instead a list of argument because I get the error:

```
'/bin/grep: Argument list too long'
```

##### EDIT 2

```
# The result of the command ls -R
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXX     1 Oct 28 23:36 README.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXX     1 Oct 28 23:36 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXX     1 Oct 28 23:36 iamaninja.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXX     1 Oct 28 23:36 donttakeme.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXX     1 Oct 28 23:36 donttakeme2.txt
```

What I want as a result:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXX     1 Oct 28 23:36 README.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXX     1 Oct 28 23:36 __init__.py
```

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: You could store the list of all files below your working directory into an array (no need for `ls`; just use _globstar_ (search the bash man-page for the `globstar` option of `shopt`)), and then loop through this array and see, whether you want to keep an entry.

Comment: @Cyrus I have never thought about it. Maybe it could be OK for very simple solutions, but I see the risk

Comment: I suggest to use `find`.

Comment: Well, I use a file instead of a list because I have a file with lots of lines. 

Take care with "Argument list too long"

Comment: What about `ls -R | grep -Ff filters.txt`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, that's the one! Only with find and xargs, maybe? Nice!

Comment: Thank for this solution. It works in the case that the data are equals. It do not works if the data *contains* (instead of being equals) the filters.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use `comm` :

```
comm -12 <(ls -R | grep -e "\.txt$" -e "\.py$" ) <(cat filters.txt)
```

This will give you the intersection of the two lists.

**EDIT**
It seems that `ls` is not great for this, maybe `find` Would be safer

Comment: Well, it can be a good start to find a solution but this imply having the same format for the ls result and filters.txt.
Unfortunately, "ls" give more information than filenames

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f | xargs grep $(sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\|/g' filters.txt)
```

That is, for each of your files, take your `filters.txt` and replace all newlines with `\|` using `sed` and then grep for all the entries.
Grep uses `\|` between items when grepping for more than one item. So the `sed` command transforms the `filters.txt` into such a list of items to be used by `grep`.

Comment: Thank for your answer :) 
The only problem is if the list is really big: Argument list too long

That's why I don't use "ls -R | grep -e file1.txt -e file2.txt ..."

Comment: Then use xargs?! :)  (updated)

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -f filters.txt -r .
```

..where `.` is your current folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this script in the target directory, giving the list file as a single argument.

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# exit early if awk fails (ie. can't read list)
shopt -s lastpipe

find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.py' -print0 |
awk -v exclude_list_file="${1?:no list file provided}" \
'BEGIN {
    while ((getline line < exclude_list_file) > 0) {
        exclude_list[c++] = line
    }

    close(exclude_list_file)

    if (c==0) {
        exit 1
    }

    FS = "/"
    RS = "\000"
}

{
    for (i in exclude_list) {
        if (exclude_list[i] == $NF) {
            next
        }
    }

    print
}'
```

- It prints all paths, recursively, excluding any filename which exactly matches a line in the list file (so lines not ending `.py` or `.txt` wouldn’t do anything).
- Only the filename is considered, the preceding path is ignored.
- It fails immediately if no argument is given or it can't read a line from the list file.
- The question is tagged `bash`, but if you change the shebang to `sh`, and remove `shopt`, then everything in the script except `-print0` is POSIX. `-print0` is common, it’s available on GNU (Linux), BSDs (including OpenBSD), and busybox.
- The purpose of `lastpipe` is to exit immediately if the list file can't be read. Without it, `find` keeps runs until completion (but nothing gets printed).
- If you specifically want the `ls -l` output format, you could change `awk` to use a null output record separator (add `ORS = "\000"` to the end of `BEGIN`, directly below `RS="\000"`), and pipe `awk` in to `xargs -0 ls -ld`.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I gonna try it